# mogrify resize file name with bracket

Tags: php, imagemagick, mogrify

in php it failed when resize file name that include "(" bracket.

normally I do

```
exec("mogrify -resize {$filewidth}x{$fileheight}! \"$file\"");
```

but it don't work with filename with bracket

by command line have to escape like this for working.

`mogrify -resize 203x126! 53v-slave-only\(2\).png`

how to fix it for php by `exec()` command

**note filename must use bracket.**

thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [escapeshellcmd](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) and [escapeshellarg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) when using functions that works with the command line.

For example:

```
<?php
$filewidth = escapeshellcmd($filewidth);
$fileheight = escapeshellcmd($fileheight);
$file = escapeshellcmd($file);

exec("mogrify -resize {$filewidth}x{$fileheight}! \"$file\"");
?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `file`* vars use `escapeshellarg` instead of `escapeshellcmd`? And then wrap the whole string with `escapeshellcmd` before calling `exec`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$file=str_replace(array('(',')'),array('\\(','\\)'),$file);
```

Comment: do you mean I better rename a filename before store it.?

Comment: No, I don't. Replace `(` by `\(` as you need and pass it to exec