# PHP code to change image format to JPG

Tags: php

I constructed this PHP code to use ImageMagick to convert gif files to jpg but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe I am missing something:

```
<?php
$cwd = getcwd();
$directory = 'temp_images/input/'; // add path to the source direcotry, reprocesses all images directly, not fancy.

$dh = opendir($directory);

while($file = readdir($dh)) {
  if (strlen($file) > 2) {
    $dirfiles[]=$file;
  }
}
closedir($dh);
reset($dirfiles);
asort($dirfiles);


set_time_limit(0);
foreach ($dirfiles as $dirfile) {
  $file = $directory.$dirfile;
  $cmd = 'mogrify -format jpg *.gif $file';     
  echo  $dirfile . " mogrified to JPG \n";
}

?>
```

The gif files are not being converted.

**UPDATE:** In my own code I replaced  with $cmd = 'mogrify -format jpg *.gif $file'; to
  exec("mogrify -format jpg *.* $file");

I was under the impression when I use mogrify the original files are purged. How do I go about it?

Comment: What command does the converting?

Comment: You never run the command `mogrify -format ...` (you're just inserting it in a variable).

Comment: $cmd = 'mogrify -format jpg *.gif $file';

Comment: No, it's just a string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881777/mogrify-resize-file-name-with-bracket note the exec :)

Comment: @ComFreek is right, you're just storing a string into a variable, but never executing that command. Look at the `exec()` documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: @What is good in this question who has vote up

Comment: Could just do `imagejpeg(imagecreatefromgif($srcfile),$dstfile);`

Answer (score 0):

The `$cmd` is never executed... it is just a string value.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong type of *'quotes'*

```
foreach ($dirfiles as $dirfile) {
  $file = $directory.$dirfile;
  $cmd = 'mogrify -format jpg *.gif $file';     
  echo  $dirfile . " mogrified to JPG \n";
}
```

You want the [back-tick operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php).

```
foreach ($dirfiles as $dirfile) {
  $file = $directory.$dirfile;
  $cmdResult = `mogrify -format jpg *.gif $file`;     
  echo  $dirfile . " mogrified to JPG \n";
}
```

This is identical to using [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).

```
foreach ($dirfiles as $dirfile) {
  $file = $directory.$dirfile;
  $cmdResult = shell_exec ( "mogrify -format jpg *.gif {$file}" );     
  echo  $dirfile . " mogrified to JPG \n";
}
```